# Docker's socket file for multiple user on Mac OS x

Tags: docker, mac-osx

I have a computer running Mac OS X. I have multiple users (let's say user1 and user2)

I have installed docker desktop for Mac.

There is something strange: I can run Docker Desktop simultaneously for the 2 users.
It seems docker daemon is launched for each user.

Each user can create its own containers. Everything is jailed per user. This is great.

But there is something I do not understand: How docker-cli can know which is the good socket file ?

Here is what I see on user1 session:

```
(user1) $ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
  /var/run/docker.sock -> /Users/user1/.docker/run/docker.sock
```

and here is what I see on user2 session, at the same time:

```
(user2) $ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
  /var/run/docker.sock -> /Users/user2/.docker/run/docker.sock
```

The same symbolic link on the same directory, on the same computer is targeting different files ! How can this be possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's fascinating indeed, I didn't know how unix domain sockets worked under the hood other than what I'm used to do with them, but from what I've could gather, there were [several](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/799) [issues](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/812) [raised](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/492) [about](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/929) [it](https://forums.docker.com/t/running-docker-under-multiple-osx-accounts-logins-solved/10462), and by reading this last link, where it's said it was fixed in version 1.11.2-beta12, I still wasn't sure where the fix was scoped from.

So more digging was necessary and from everything I've learned so far, the Darwin Kernel lacked the capability to implement POSIX compliant Unix Domain Sockets until June 2017, where they [published](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/commit/3eaa6b2cf6d66cebc3974fffeb31fc70175aa59b) [socketvar.h](https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/xnu/xnu-123.5.tar.gz) that implements authentication on Unix Domain Sockets.

I still can't explain how the same socket is symbolically linking to a different file in the filesystem, pointing to the users' $DOCKER_HOME. But I suspect it's part of the same set of features implemented in 2017.

Someone with more knowledge on OSX Darwin Kernel release notes could shed some more light onto the topic, but my detective work can only lead me so far.

Thanks for your question, it led me to an incredible rabbit-hole.

Comment: IIRC, `/var` itself is a symlink to `/private/var` which is likely unique per user as the name implies. I don't have a macOS at hand right now but you might be able to investigate further 

Comment: Thanks, yes /var is a symlink to /private/var/. But /private is the same folder for all mac os users ? (This is not a symlink to a /Users/ subfolder)

Comment: The /private "likely" being unique per user... That's the information I couldn't confirm with my investigation.